# Hazelcast SqlPredicate from IMap values gives the ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have setup hazelcast with 3 nodes in my system and i have connected with spring boot application , in spring boot application i am connecting through `hazelcast-client.yaml`

```
 hazelcast-client:
  user-code-deployment:
    enabled: true
    jarPaths:
      - build\libs\hazelcast-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    classNames:
      - org.learning.cache.hazelcast.entity.Location
  network:
    cluster-members:
      - 127.0.0.1:5701
    smart-routing: false
```

I am able to connect succefully , but when i do SqlPredict query its not giving me the data, sample code snippet for the same

```
public List<Location> locations(Integer id, String accountId, String currency) {
        IMap<Integer, Location> locationIMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("location");
        if (id != null && accountId != null && currency != null) {
            String query = "locationId = " + id + " AND accountId =" + accountId + " AND currency =" + currency;
            Collection<Location> result = locationIMap.values(new SqlPredicate(query));
            if (result != null) {
                return result.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        }
```

The error i get when call this logic

```
2021-02-05 10:55:57,722 [ERROR] [hz.epic_sanderson.partition-operation.thread-1] [c.h.m.i.q.QueryPartitionOperation]: [10.1.0.9]:5701 [dev] [4.1.1] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.learning.cache.hazelcast.entity.Location
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.learning.cache.hazelcast.entity.Location
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:87) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:76) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:205) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getValue(CachedQueryEntry.java:78) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getTargetObject(CachedQueryEntry.java:123) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:124) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:80) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.readAttributeValue(AbstractPredicate.java:145) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.apply(AbstractPredicate.java:62) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.PartitionScanRunner$1.accept(PartitionScanRunner.java:110) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.PartitionScanRunner$1.accept(PartitionScanRunner.java:94) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.forEach(DefaultRecordStore.java:234) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.forEach(DefaultRecordStore.java:218) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.forEachAfterLoad(DefaultRecordStore.java:247) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.PartitionScanRunner.run(PartitionScanRunner.java:94) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.CallerRunsPartitionScanExecutor.execute(CallerRunsPartitionScanExecutor.java:43) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryRunner.runPartitionIndexOrPartitionScanQueryOnGivenOwnedPartition(QueryRunner.java:219) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryPartitionOperation.runInternal(QueryPartitionOperation.java:46) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.MapOperation.run(MapOperation.java:112) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.call(Operation.java:184) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:256) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:237) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:452) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:166) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:136) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102) [hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.learning.cache.hazelcast.entity.Location
        at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:289) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:249) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:783) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1995) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:83) ~[hazelcast-all-4.1.1.jar
```

hazelcast version  "hazelcast-all-4.1.1"
spring boot version : 2.2.3.RELEASE

It seems that LocationEntity class might not present in any of the Hazelcast member , but not able to find how to fix this issue , appreciated for any help Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There is an error is in your `hazelcast-client.yaml` file.

The first line should read:

```
hazelcast-client:
```

not

```
hazelcast:
```

If you add this,

```
    @Bean
    public ClientConfig clientConfig() throws Exception {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new YamlClientConfigBuilder("hazelcast-client.yaml").build();
        return clientConfig;
    }
```

You can print what's loaded, makes it easier to validate if the configuration you've specified is found.

Comment: yeah i had typo issue , its hazelcast-client: only but still its gives the same error

Comment: So you're not trying to use `user-code-deployment:` now ?

Comment: I used the User Code Deployment on client and member side also , but getting diffent exception now .
``Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader cannot access its superinterface org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.FileHeader (org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader is in unnamed module ``

Comment: Which probllem do you need to solve ? Using `user-code-deployment` or making the `Location` class available to the Hazelcast server at start-up ?  If it's the former that would be a separate issue as it's unrelated. If it's the latter, can you clarify how you start the Hazelcast server(s).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response now i dont have classNotFoundException after using User code deployment  , now issue is ``Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError`` I have setup hazelcast using helm ``https://hazelcast.com/blog/hazelcast-helm-chart/`` , shall i change the question ? my issues is that after adding the user-code-deployment also its not working ,

Comment: here is my slack-hazelcast thread also
``https://app.slack.com/client/T01331THEQL/C015Q2TUBKL/thread/C015Q2TUBKL-1607366785.100700``

Comment: adding github link also ``https://github.com/panditb/poc`` with this install Hezalcat helm chart as followed "https://hazelcast.com/blog/hazelcast-helm-chart/"